# Does the UI thread have priority over web workers?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

If I do a seconds long computation in a web worker, can I expect the UI to not stutter because of it? Including mobile? If not, what can I do about it? The workload is easy to split up into smaller chunks, but about half the site doesn't work until that computation is done.

Comment: This anecdotal evidence from 2012 seems to say that back then, the UI thread studdered on heavy web worker load https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758999/how-to-handle-massive-computation-on-websites-web-workers-or-cgi

Comment: *massive* and *long computation* are a bit subjective. In general, load on web worker shouldn't affect the UI thread. Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to offload into the worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...can I expect the UI to not stutter because of it?

Largely, yes, you can, within the limits of the capability of the browser and device. This is, after all, the *raison d'être* of web workers: To move long-running processes off the UI thread so the UI can remain responsive. There are no guarantees, but... Empirically: I've done tests where the worker busy-loops for 30+ seconds while the main UI updates, and it works just fine on desktop, Android, and iOS.

Such tests are not difficult:

[Live on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/76lkCsgfcjOgwyi6T8Hi?p=preview)

Live snippet (may not work on all devices because of how I'm creating the worker):

```js
const chars = "|/-\\".split("");
let charindex = -1;
const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
setInterval(() => {
    charindex = (charindex + 1) % chars.length;
    spinner.innerHTML = chars[charindex];
}, 50);
function log(msg) {
    const p = document.createElement("pre");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
function main() {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([
        document.getElementById("worker").textContent
      ], {type: "text/javascript"})
    );
    const w = new Worker(url);
    w.onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event.data === "ready") {
            w.postMessage("start");
        } else {
            log(event.data);
        }
    };
}
main();
```

```html
<div id="spinner"></div>
<script id="worker" type="worker">
this.addEventListener("message", e => {
    if (e.data === "start") {
        let last = Date.now();
        const stop = last + 20000;
        let now;
        while ((now = Date.now()) < stop) {
            if (now - last > 1000) {
                postMessage("tick");
                last = now;
            }
        }
    }
});
postMessage("ready");
</script>
```

`worker.js`:

```
this.addEventListener("message", e => {
    if (e.data === "start") {
        let last = Date.now();
        const stop = last + 30000;
        let now;
        while ((now = Date.now()) < stop) {
            if (now - last > 1000) {
                postMessage("tick");
                last = now;
            }
        }
    }
});
postMessage("ready");
```

`host.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Worker Host</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="spinner"></div>
<script>
const chars = "|/-\\".split("");
let charindex = -1;
const spinner = document.getElementById("spinner");
setInterval(() => {
    charindex = (charindex + 1) % chars.length;
    spinner.innerHTML = chars[charindex];
}, 50);
function log(msg) {
    const p = document.createElement("pre");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
function main() {
    const w = new Worker("worker.js");
    w.onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event.data === "ready") {
            w.postMessage("start");
        } else {
            log(event.data);
        }
    };
}
main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I found http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-webworkers/ and ran it with 16+ threads without too much UI lag on desktop or on mobile